# Is WindowExecution array return from DescribeMaintenanceWindowExecutions api is order by StartTime property?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

In sample response in documentation it seems like it is sorted by StartTime property.
[doc link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeMaintenanceWindowExecutions.html)

```
{
    "NextToken": "AAEABbrXFUcgJpmXZxxu+AD17F+5bzlsAyqrig1EXAMPLE...pYY",
    "WindowExecutions": [
        {
            "WindowId": "mw-0c50858d01EXAMPLE",
            "WindowExecutionId": "6027b513-64fe-4cf0-be7d-1191aEXAMPLE",
            "Status": "IN_PROGRESS",
            "StartTime": "2021-08-04T11:00:00.000000-07:00"
        },
        {
            "WindowId": "mw-0c50858d01EXAMPLE",
            "WindowExecutionId": "ff75b750-4834-4377-8f61-b3cadEXAMPLE",
            "Status": "SUCCESS",
            "StartTime": "2021-08-03T11:00:00.000000-07:00",
            "EndTime": "2021-08-03T11:37:21.450000-07:00"
        },
        {
            "WindowId": "mw-0c50858d01EXAMPLE",
            "WindowExecutionId": "9fac7dd9-ff21-42a5-96ad-bbc4bEXAMPLE",
            "Status": "FAILED",
            "StatusDetails": "One or more tasks in the orchestration failed.",
            "StartTime": "2021-08-02T11:00:00.000000-07:00",
            "EndTime": "2021-08-02T11:22:36.190000-07:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

But documentation does not specifically said array is sorted. Where can I find more detail document about how this api returns WindowExecution array? Is it sorted or not?